# lzma: initrd.lz: File format not recognized

Tags: live-cd, archive

I'm using this command to extract initrd.lz archive file:

```
lzma -dc -S .lz initrd.lz | cpio -id
```

For ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso/casper/initrd.lz this command is working perfect.

But for Elementary OS 0.3 Freya Beta 2

[elementaryos-unstable-amd64.20150208/casper/initrd.lz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9v1AQvi2Us8REtNenFlT3ZPMXc/view?usp=sharing)

I'm getting this error:

[image]

How can I extract this [initrd.lz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9v1AQvi2Us8REtNenFlT3ZPMXc/view?usp=sharing) file?

**EDIT:**

I tried Lzip:

[image]

Comment: It's a lzip file format, so you need to install lzip package. http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/manual/lzip_manual.html

Comment: I tried Lzip, I edited the question. I'm getting (file not in lzip format) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `file`command to find out the file type:

```
$ file initrd.lz 
initrd.lz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sun Feb  8 22:26:04 2015
```

So it tells you it's just a gzip file with a strange suffix. Since `gunzip` refuses to decompress files not having the right suffix, either rename the file or tell it to use a different suffix:

```
gunzip --suffix lz initrd.lz
```